# How do I programmatically change the Title in a wpf window?

Tags: c#, wpf

How do I programmatically change the Title in a wpf window?

```
<Window x:Class="Temp.MainWindow"
 ...
 Title="Contacts">
```

Change the Title from "Contacts" to "Something new" when the program finds new information as it starts.

Comment: You should use [binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Bind the title property of window to a property of your DataContext.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

To change it you can simply alter the Title property from your code:

```
this.Title = "Something new";
```

Answer (score 30):

Bind it to a property

```
Title="{Binding WindowTitle}"
```

Comment: Which one of these two answers is the preferred way? My guess is that binding to a property is the best way.

Comment: If you are using an MVVM (or similar) approach then binding would be preferred.